# I recompiled dozens of times, why is my OpenSSL Library and Header still not the same?

Tags: php5, openssl

```
openssl

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

From PHP (5.4.4) info, this is the problem I have. I am dry out of ideas, and I cannot understand why it ins't working.

This was my configure:

```
./configure 
'--with-apxs2=/etc/apache24/bin/apxs' 
'--with-mysql' 
'--prefix=/etc/apache24/php' 
'--with-config-file-path=/etc/apache24/php' 
'--enable-force-cgi-redirect' 
'--disable-cgi' 
'--with-zlib' 
'--with-gettext' 
'--with-curl' 
'--with-mcrypt' 
'--with-gd' 
'--with-pdo' 
'--with-pdo-mysql' 
'--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
'--with-libdir=lib32' 
'--with-openssl=shared,/usr'
 '--with-mysqli'
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're *linking* against the wrong version of OpenSSL.  You've got the right headers, but for whatever reason (and given the amount of damage you've done to your system, based on  your past questions, the possible reasons are nearly *endless*), the linker is still finding and using the old 0.9.8 version of libssl you've got laying around.

Personally, I'd tell your PCI auditor to go jam his nessus scan up his fundament, but if you're not feeling so adventurous, at least get someone who knows how to build software to get onto your machine, work out what you're doing wrong, and fix it.  We're not going to be able to reverse engineer your system on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I just needed to do a `make clean` and the next time I compiled it both openssl header and library versions were the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me that was very non-obvious issue. And I have found that php-**extension load order can be important** sometimes!

If we have, for example, curl.so linked with older libssl.so and openssl.so linked with newer libssl.so and if curl.so loaded before openssl.so then both extensions will use older openssl library.

So in your case you have compiled in curl extension which probably uses libcurl linked with old ssl library so old ssl library loaded before your openssl extension.